# Как отобрать нужные div'ы?

Tags: jquery

В разметке нужно отобрать те div'ы, которые содержат нужные ссылки.

```
<div class="z"><a>1</a></div>
<div class="z"><a>2</a></div>
```

Я делаю так

```
$(".z").children("a").click(function(event){ ... }));
```

и выбираю все div'ы, которые содержат ссылки. Как из этих div'ов выбрать те, которые в теле ссылки содержат цифру 1? То есть как фильтровать по содержанию ссылок?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Упс. Уже нашел. :) Нужен селектор [contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/), который фильтрует по содержимому текста.

```
$(".z").children("a:contains('1')").click(function(event){ ... }));
```