# Как написать составной селектор?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Вопрос, связанный с [темой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/4656/) про отбор div'ов. Селектор вида

```
"a:contains('text')"
```

работает для ссылок вида `<a>text</a>`. Если ссылки могут содержать разные строки:

```
var texts = { ... }
```

как составить селектор, который отберет все ссылки, которые содержат хотя бы одну строку из полного набора строк?

---

Сделал так (все работает):

```
$(".z").filter(function() {
    var found = false;

    $(this).find("a").each(function(){
        link = $(this).text();

        for (var t in texts) {
            if (link == t) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    });

    return found;
}).click(function(event){ ... }));
```

Если кто-то знает решение лучше, просьба отписаться :)

Comment: А почему нельзя пометить нужные ссылки каким-нибудь классом? И ещё, если строки в texts не совсем любые, то можно попробовать wildcards. Также, решением получше будет выделение части этой хрени в отдельную функцию.

Comment: Ссылки и нужно пометить требуемым классом. Строки не совсем любые, но вариантов может быть много.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да вот так сработает же

```
var selector = texts.map(function() {
    return "a:contains('" + this + "')"; // тут надо осторожно с кавычками текста
}).join(",");

$(selector). doSometing..
```

[Тут про это написано для простых случаев](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

Как насчет циклом проверить каждый элемент 'texts'? В jQuery не силен, но как насчет такого:

```
var i, selectors;
var texts = { ... }
for(i = 0; i < size(texts); i++){
    selectors += $("a:contains(texts[i])");
}
```

Не ругайте за банальные ошибки :)

Comment: Так не будет работать. :) А каждый элемент texts проверять - идея нормальная. Похоже, так и придется.

Comment: Может и не будет, просто набросал на скорую руку :)

Answer (score 0):

можно через регэкспы сделать

```
var regex = /(text1|text2|text3)/i;

$('a').each( function () {
 if (regex.test($(this).text() ) ) {
  // найдено
 }
} );
```